# UI behavior depending on type - what's the pattern behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, design-patterns

I have a web page for editing a **product** and the UI has **different behavior** depending on **product** type.

**It consist in minor changes like**:
 A specific field is mandatory just for one product type, a dropdown list has fewer options for 2 product types, an `ajax` call is made to a different URL, etc.

1/ How can I write an "elegant" code in JavaScript, so I would like to respect open-closed principle and to avoid conditions like:

```
var idType = $('#idtype').val();
if (idType == 3)
```

...

2/ Is there a way to use `"enums"` in JavaScript?

3/ Is there a design-pattern that refers to this situation? The closest I know is `Strategy` pattern.

4/ In my case, those changes can be handled in `JavaScript` code. But how should **I model** the case when behavior is different on **client-side and server-side**?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use switch, look the example below.
2. Not in a native mode, but you can simulate one, for example:

   ```
   var MyEnum = {
       LittleBall: 1,
       MediumBall: 2,
       BigBall: 3
   };

   var idType = parseInt($("#idtype").val(), 10);

   switch(idType) {
       case MyEnum.LittleBall:
           // do stuff here
           break;
       case MyEnum.MediumBall:
           // do stuff here
           break;
       case MyEnum.BigBall:
           // do stuff here
           break;
       default:
           break;
   }
   ```
3. What do you mean about patterns?
4. Your client-side behavior should never be different than the server-side one.

Comment: What about open-closed principle?

Answer (score 0):

This is why inheritance exists. Put the "normal" scenarios into `Product`. Make it a prototype  for `ThatProductWithFewerOptions`, `ThatProductWithMandatoryField` etc. Override functions that differ from the general `Product`. Have a lookup that maps from IDs to product constructors; if it's none of the special ones, you can use `Product`. Then just call `product.checkMandatoryFields()`, `product.ajaxURL` etc. No more `if`s.

Alternately, handle all the differences server-side (again, classes work wonders). This way you don't need to implement everything twice. Or if you have Node.js serverside, the same code can function on both ends.

I suppose that's the Factory pattern, if I really needed to name it (`Product.getInstanceFor(idType)`).